# OpenCV Erode and Dilate switched

Tags: opencv

I'm curious why does when I try to dilate the picture, the background expands, and the object in the foreground shrink. And when I try to erode the picture, the background shrinks, and the object expands. should it be the other way around?

```
 int type = 2;
    int size = 5;
    Mat element = getStructuringElement( type, Size( 2*size + 1, 2*size + 1), Point( size, size ));
    switch( filterEnhan )
    {
        case 0: out=img.clone();
            break;
        case 1: morphologyEx(img, out, MORPH_DILATE, element);
            break;
        case 2: morphologyEx(img, out, MORPH_ERODE, element);
            break;
        case 3:morphologyEx(img, out, MORPH_OPEN, element);
            break;
    }
```

Original image :
[image: Original Image]

After dilatation : 
[image: After dilatation:]

After erosion:
[image: After Erosion:]

Comment: It depends on what your convention is for foreground and background. Eroding the foreground is the same as dilating the background. Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong operation. In the docs you can find that for the function `morphologyEx()` the allowed values are:

- MORPH_OPEN - an opening operation
- MORPH_CLOSE - a closing operation
- MORPH_GRADIENT - a morphological gradient
- MORPH_TOPHAT - "top hat"
- MORPH_BLACKHAT - "black hat"

You are calling it with `MORPH_DILATE` and `MORPH_ERODE` which are not allowed here. These two constants are intended for use in the function `createMorphologyFilter`. The reason it doesn't crash is, that those named constants are actually numbers - 1, 2, 3 etc.

So you are in range thus no crash, but actually you are doing some other operation.

For erosion and dilation use functions: `erode()` and `dilate()`.

Comment: doesn't had any effect after I change into erode() and dilate()